# SQL Script to Exclude Weekends and Holidays

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a query where I need to add 2 days to the date variable based on a condition.

However, this date variable needs to skip weekends and holidays.

I have a table that stores holidays. How do I integrate this into my query?

So currently I check if the date is a weekend. If so then I add 1 or 2 days. However, if that date is a holiday I then need to add another day. And then check if that date is a holiday or a weekend!

Is there a script that I could use for this?

Comment: When asking for a query, it helps to have table definitions and sample data, as well as expected output. Please see [help us help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)

Answer (score 2):

This is really a T-SQL question and would be better off on StackOverflow.

That said, you can use the following to determine if the date falls on a weekend:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) -- Friday
SELECT DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) -- 6
```

And determining if the date falls on a holiday (by querying against your holiday table) should be trivial.

I recommend you have a stab yourself. If it works, great - if not, post what you have so far, plus your specific problem on SO.

Comment: `DATEPART()` may return a different number based on [`DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) and possibly localization/regional settings. One can't assume that `Friday` *always* equals 6.

Answer (score 1):

Use a most handy ***Calendar table***, which is a table that holds a row for each day with custom markers (like `IsHoliday`, `IsFirstOfMonth`, `IsFirstMondayOfMonth`, etc.), and any other column you might need (like `BusinessHourStartTime`, `BusinessHourEndTime`, etc.).

You can generate one recursively following this `SELECT`.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2025-01-01'

DECLARE @HolidaysTbl as TABLE (HolidayDate date)
INSERT INTO @HolidaysTbl(HolidayDate) VALUES('2018-12-13'), ('2018-12-17'), ('2018-12-19');

;WITH GeneratedDates AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = @StartDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, G.GeneratedDate)
    FROM
        GeneratedDates AS G
    WHERE
        G.GeneratedDate < @EndDate
),
SpecialDays AS
(
    SELECT
        Date = G.GeneratedDate,
        Year = YEAR(G.GeneratedDate),
        Month = MONTH(G.GeneratedDate),
        Day = DAY(G.GeneratedDate),
        IsWeekend = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, G.GeneratedDate) IN (6, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        IsHoliday = CASE WHEN H.HolidayDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        GeneratedDates AS G
        LEFT JOIN @HolidaysTbl AS H ON G.GeneratedDate = H.HolidayDate
)
SELECT
    Date = S.Date,
    Year = S.Year,
    Month = S.Month,
    Day = S.Day,
    IsWeekend = S.IsWeekend,
    IsHoliday = S.IsHoliday,
    BusinessHoursStartTime = CASE WHEN S.IsHoliday = 0 AND S.IsWeekend = 0 THEN CONVERT(TIME, '09:00') END,
    BusinessHoursEndTIme = CASE WHEN S.IsHoliday = 0 AND S.IsWeekend = 0 THEN CONVERT(TIME, '18:00') END,
    WorkingDaysOrder = CASE 
        WHEN S.IsHoliday = 0 AND S.IsWeekend = 0 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY 
            S.IsHoliday ASC,
            S.IsWeekend ASC,
            S.Date ASC) END
FROM
    SpecialDays AS S
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Which generates rows like this:

```
Date        Year    Month   Day     IsWeekend   IsHoliday   BusinessHoursStartTime  BusinessHoursEndTIme    WorkingDaysOrder
2018-01-01  2018    1       1       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        1
2018-01-02  2018    1       2       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        2
2018-01-03  2018    1       3       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        3
2018-01-04  2018    1       4       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        4
2018-01-05  2018    1       5       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        5
2018-01-06  2018    1       6       1           0           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-07  2018    1       7       1           0           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-08  2018    1       8       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        6
2018-01-09  2018    1       9       0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        7
2018-01-10  2018    1       10      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        8
2018-01-11  2018    1       11      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        9
2018-01-12  2018    1       12      0           1           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-13  2018    1       13      1           0           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-14  2018    1       14      1           0           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-15  2018    1       15      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        10
2018-01-16  2018    1       16      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        11
2018-01-17  2018    1       17      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        12
2018-01-18  2018    1       18      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        13
2018-01-19  2018    1       19      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        14
2018-01-20  2018    1       20      1           0           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-21  2018    1       21      1           0           NULL                    NULL                    NULL
2018-01-22  2018    1       22      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        15
2018-01-23  2018    1       23      0           0           09:00:00.0000000        18:00:00.0000000        16
```

So when you need to add days and the result has to be a working day you can simply find your queried date in the table, retrieve it's `WorkingDaysOrder`, add 2 days (for example) and bring back it's associated `Date`.

```
DECLARE @DateToAddDays DATE = '2018-01-10' -- Wednesday
DECLARE @AmountOfDaysToAdd INT = 2

SELECT 
    D.Date 
FROM
    Calendar AS D
WHERE
    D.WorkingDaysOrder = @AmountOfDaysToAdd + (SELECT T.WorkingDaysOrder FROM Calendar AS T WHERE T.Date = @DateToAddDays)

-- Result: 2018-01-15 (Monday, day 12 is Holiday, 13 and 14 weekend)
```

Calendar tables will help you with most of your dates problems, like counting working hours between 2 dates or finding the 3rd Sunday on each month. It doesn't have many rows and makes date and time handling very easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Yes I managed to use the below script with my holidays tbl. The @numDays variable is the total days to add onto the initial date (@addDate)

```
 DECLARE @HolidaysTbl as TABLE
 (
   HolidayDate date
 );

 INSERT INTO @HolidaysTbl(HolidayDate) VALUES('2012-12-13'), ('2012-12-17'), ('2012-12-19');

--select * from @HolidaysTbl

declare @addDate AS DATE = '2012-12-13', @numDays AS  INT = 5;

select CAST(@addDate  AS  DATETIME), DATENAME(DW,CAST(@addDate  AS  DATETIME)) as 'InitialDate'

WHILE @numDays>0
BEGIN
   SET @addDate=DATEADD(d,1,@addDate);

   IF DATENAME(DW,@addDate) = 'saturday' SET @addDate = DATEADD(d,1,@addDate);
   IF DATENAME(DW,@addDate) = 'sunday' SET  @addDate = DATEADD(d,1,@addDate);
   WHILE @addDate IN (SELECT HolidayDate FROM @HolidaysTbl WHERE HolidayDate = @addDate)
   BEGIN
        SELECT 'TEST', @addDate, DATENAME(DW,CAST(@addDate  AS  DATETIME))
        SET  @addDate = DATEADD(d,1,@addDate);
        SELECT 'TEST2', @addDate, DATENAME(DW,CAST(@addDate  AS  DATETIME))
   END

   SET @numDays=@numDays-1;
END

select CAST(@addDate  AS  DATETIME), DATENAME(DW,CAST(@addDate  AS  DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can simply use datediff function of sql. and then you can subtract weekends between those dates if any. For example check below query.

```
    Declare @startdatee as DateTime
    Declare @enddatee as DateTime
    Set @startdatee = GETDATE();
    set @enddatee = GETDATE()+1;
    select @startdatee,@enddatee,(datediff(day,@startdatee,@enddatee+1)-(2)*datediff(week,@startdatee,@enddatee))
```

And If You want to exclude holiday's too, then, You also can calculate holidays between start/end date and can subtract that from final selection. i gave you example here. You can use your holiday's table,here i am just using temp table for example.

```
Declare @holidays Table (ID int,Name Varchar(50),[Date] date)
Insert into @holidays VALUES 
(1,'holiday1','2018-07-07'),
(2,'holiday2','2018-07-12')

Declare 
    @startdate datetime = '2018-07-02',
    @enddate datetime =  '2018-07-30',
    @holiday int = 0

    Set @holiday = (Select COUNT(*) FROM @holidays WHERE (Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) 
                    AND DATEPART(Weekday,Date) not in (1,7)
                    )

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(case datepart(dw, @StartDate) when 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
  -(case datepart(dw, @EndDate) when 7 then 1 else 0 end)
  -@holiday
```

this is much simple and easy query then other.

Comment: Does subtracting the amount of weeks * 2 not possibly overestimate the amount of weekend-days that need to be subtracted? I.e. if an event starts on Jan 8th 2023 and ends on Jan 20th 2023, the amount of days that should be subtracted is 3 (2 sundays, 1 saturday), not 4.